# Creating a calculator, 2 types of "computation methods", have they a name?

Tags: parsing, calculator

Beginner in programming here and non-native english speaker, sorry for the weird formulations..

I am trying to create a calculator, and there seem to be 2 types of logic when computing an expression.

If i input the sequence 2+5*3 in a certain type of calculator (like the one on windows, or any phone), the result will be 21.

If i input this same sequence in another type of calculator this same sequence,
the result will be 17.

The reason for this is of course that the first kind of calculator is calculating "on the fly" : (2+5), then multiplies this by 3, while the second evaluates the whole expression and respects the multiply priority, 2+(5*3).

So the first calculator computes (2+5)*3 and the second computes 2+(5*3)

**My question is:** have these 2 "methods" an "official" name ? Like "stack method" or something ?

**Bottom line is** that I would like to allow the user to switch between these 2 methods, and i don't know how to call them..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The correct value for 2 + 5 * 3 is 17. If some calculator gives 21 as the answer, then that calculator is wrong.

Comment: Like @jesper said, only 17 is the correct answer. You shouldn't be able to 'switch' the calculator, because it's mathematically incorrect to get the answer 21. Source:  https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html

Comment: I think that i made a mistake in how i computed the sequence with the windows calculator!  I would actually press enter after entering the 5 (as to confirm my choice) -> which would compute the 2+5 expression, and then multiply by 3. 
DUMB ME ! SORRY

Comment: Exactly ! I just checked that.. I was not crazy after all !